# itemize in reledpar paragraphs

Tags: itemize, reledpar

Enthusiasts,

The right-side of my reledpar "Pages"-Environment constitutes a series of notes glossing on each left-side paragraph. I have found that if the right side paragraphs are held in the "itemize" environment, there is a blank page after each first line, and the consecutive lines's spacing becomes tighter. Is there a way

1)Either to insert blank lines between individual notes within each (right-side) paragraphs

or

2) Make the "itemize" environment work

without confusing the automatic paragraph-height synchronization spacing?

Thanks in advance,

Jigdrel

Comment: Itemize actually does not work on reledmac/reledpar. I have no time to do all the issue opened on reledmac/reledpar. You should imitate \item feature by inserting linebreak (\\) and manualy item bullet.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. \linebreak and then leaving an empty line leaves the exact result I was looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.